# How to write a entire row in excel from an array - xlwt

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I would like to improve my code, replacing this:

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("WS") 

header = [u'Nome da estação',u'Altitude',u'Latitude',u'Longitude']

column =0
for h in header:
    sheet.write(0, column, h)
    column += 1
```

For some code to use directly the array header to write an entire line. Any idea?

Comment: `for c, h in enumerate(header): sheet.write(0, c, h)` is already an improvement.

Comment: Sure is a good improvement! Thanks! But I was thinking related to constructor of a row or something else related to write an array natively like a method of the sheet.

Comment: There does not appear to be such a method. Given the way that excel stores data in a cell-by-cell format, you probably wouldn't get much mileage out of such a method anyway. If you are just looking for the convenience of not typing as much, write your own utility method.

Comment: OK, I understood. Really, I didn't still found.Thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and posted an answer you you to select and updoot when you have time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are unlikely to get any actual improvement from writing your data as a row unit because Excel stores cells individually either way. That is probably why there is no such method documented for `xlwt`.

You can cut your code down by a couple of lines by using enumerate:

```
workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("WS") 

header = [u'Nome da estação',u'Altitude',u'Latitude',u'Longitude']

for column, heading in enumerate(header):
    sheet.write(0, column, heading)
```

If you find yourself doing this sort of thing regularly, write a small utility method:

```
def write_header(header, row=0, start_col=0):
    for column, heading in enumerate(header, start_col):
        sheet.write(row, column, heading)

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet("WS") 

write_header([u'Nome da estação',u'Altitude',u'Latitude',u'Longitude'])
```

The additional parameters will allow you to set the upper-left corner of the header in the spreadsheet should you ever need to. The default values should cover 99% of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

There's only `sheet.write()`, which writes for `row_index, column_index`.

If you're are worried about speed or optimization, just focus on optimizing the `for` loops, like you would for any other programming flow.

`workbook.save()` is required only once at the end -- so the file I/O still happens only once.